# Zipping of Files datewise

Tags: vb.net, zip

I have log files that are created datewise from an application developed in VB.NET like "Product.15082012.txt", "Product.16082012.txt" and "Service.15082012.txt", "Service.16082012.txt" under "C:\Logs". The format of the log files created are "Product.ddMMyyyy.txt" and "Service.ddMMyyyy.txt"

I need to loop through the log files in the folder "C:\Logs" for the past 6 months and zip it like "archive.15082012.zip" and "archive.16082012.zip" under "C:\Logs\Archive" through a separate archive application.

I mean while looping through the folder, it should zip Product and Service in one zip file datewise.

How can I do that? I know how to zip the files but don't know how to pickup the files datewise and group "Product.ddMMyyyy.txt" and "Service.ddMMyyyy.txt"

```
Private Sub AddToArchive(ByVal zip As Package, ByVal fileToAdd As String)
    'Replace spaces with an underscore (_) 
    Dim uriFileName As String = fileToAdd.Replace(" ", "_")

    'A Uri always starts with a forward slash "/" 
    Dim zipUri As String = String.Concat("/", _
               IO.Path.GetFileName(uriFileName))

    Dim partUri As New Uri(zipUri, UriKind.Relative)
    Dim contentType As String = _
               Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip

    'The PackagePart contains the information: 
    ' Where to extract the file when it's extracted (partUri) 
    ' The type of content stream (MIME type):  (contentType) 
    ' The type of compression:  (CompressionOption.Normal)   
    Dim pkgPart As PackagePart = zip.CreatePart(partUri, _
               contentType, CompressionOption.Normal)

    'Read all of the bytes from the file to add to the zip file 
    Dim bites As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(fileToAdd)

    'Compress and write the bytes to the zip file 
    pkgPart.GetStream().Write(bites, 0, bites.Length)

End Sub
```

Comment: You can use the System.IO.Directory and fetch all files with a specific filter and then add all of them to the zip file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find a sample below for your scenario.

```
Private Shared Function GetZipFile(ByVal zipFileNameWithPath As String, ByVal parallelDeflateThreshold As Integer) As ZipFile
    Dim zip = New ZipFile(zipFileNameWithPath)
    zip.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestCompression
    ' For using multiple threads to compress the files. 
    '-1 for single thread and never use parallel deflat 
    '0 for always use parallel deflate
    zip.ParallelDeflateThreshold = parallelDeflateThreshold
    'For  very larger files of size more than 2GB after compression
    zip.UseZip64WhenSaving = Zip64Option.AsNecessary
    Return (zip)
End Function
Public Shared Sub ZipFiles(ByVal filesToZip As List(Of System.IO.FileInfo), ByVal zipFileNameWithPath As String, ByVal parallelDeflateThreshold As Integer)
    Dim fileInfo As New System.IO.FileInfo(zipFileNameWithPath)
    If fileInfo IsNot Nothing Then
        fileInfo.Delete()
    End If
    Using zip = GetZipFile(zipFileNameWithPath, parallelDeflateThreshold)
        For Each file In filesToZip
            zip.AddFile(file.FullName, String.Empty)
        Next
        zip.Save()
    End Using
End Sub
Public Shared Sub GetFiles(ByVal folderPath As String)
    Dim directory As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(folderPath)
    Dim startDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6)
    Dim datesFilterList As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    While startDate <= DateTime.Now
        datesFilterList.Add(startDate.ToString("ddMMyyyy"), String.Concat("*.", startDate.ToString("ddMMyyyy"), ".txt"))
        startDate = startDate.AddDays(1)
    End While
    For Each filter As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In datesFilterList
        Dim files As System.IO.FileInfo() = directory.GetFiles(filter.Value)
        If files.Count > 0 Then
            Dim zipFileName As String = String.Concat("\archive.", filter.Key.ToString(), ".zip")
            ZipFiles(files.ToList(), String.Concat(folderPath, "\Archive", zipFileName), 0)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

You would need a reference to the following Iconic.Zip.dll which can be downloaded from [here](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/releases/view/68268).

NOTE: I have assumed that your folder structure looks like as below:

[image: Folder Structure]